# Fair 5-sided die

Tags: probability, geometry

Commonly used polyhedral dice all have sides of the same shape. However: is this strictly required?

Take a triangular prism. A triangular prism with small height compared to the base edge would almost always fall on one of its bases when thrown. A triangular prism with large height would fall like a "three-sided cylinder", almost always on one of the flat sides.

How would a fair triangular prism that falls on any of its sides with equal probability look?

Comment: [Maybe relevant](http://www.aleakybos.ch/Shapes.htm#_Modified_Prisms)

Comment: If you believe the probability of landing on a base varies *continuously* from $1$ to $0$ as the height of the prism varies from $0$ to $\infty$, then the Intermediate Value Theorem says there is a prism for which the probability if $1/5$.  If you believe the probability strictly *decreases* with increasing height, there is exactly one "fair" prism.

Comment: I would opt for the icosahedron, and color some subsets of four out of twenty faces the same way.

Comment: Not completely irrelevant : http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5884794

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lacking symmetry this question cannot be answered purely mathematically. We need some physics: When the die is tossed against the table surface, it bounces and rotates irregularly until it comes to halt in one of finitely many states of equilibrum. The probability distribution governing this final state can be viewed as following Boltzmann statistics so that the die lands on face $j$ with probability
$$p_j\sim e^{-E_j/kT}.$$
Here $E_j$ is the potential energy of state $j$, which is proportional to the height of the center of gravity over the table, $k$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ the temperature. The only way to make all probabiliteies equal is to esure that the potential energy is the same for all faces (or for an approximate solution make the room real hot).

If the prism has height $h$ and side length $a$ (and is homogenous of course), then the center of gravity is either at height $\frac h2$ or $\frac a{\sqrt 3}$. Therefore, you need $a=\frac{h\sqrt3} 2$.

Note that the assumption about the applicability of Boltzmann may not be justified if the die does not bounce a lot - I suppose that in that case the final position is mostly governed by the size of its "basin of attraction", essentially tha spacial angle covered by each face ...
I suggest you get out your fretsaw and make a *long* series of experiments to verify if such a 5-die is fair.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of adding symmetry by considering the polyhedron as a sphere partitioned into equal-area regions, but I'm not sure if "cutting away" the spherical portions would preserve the fairness (each face would still take the same spatial angle, measured from center).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a die that has five numbers that occur with equal probability you could either have a pentagonal prism which you have to roll (with the end faces unmarked), or you could have a regular icosahedron with each of the five numbers repeated four times on the faces, which could be tossed in the usual way.

For a triangular prism where we include the end faces, presumably the triangular face would be equilateral, and the length would have to be arrived at by experiment. You couldn't assume, for example, that square faces would make the die fair, or even that it would be fair if the areas of the rectangular faces were equal to the area of the triangular faces.

However, it is reasonable to assume that there must exist a proportion for the rectangular faces that would make the die fair.

Comment: +1 for the icosahedral solution. But I disagree with your final paragraph $-$ such a die that is fair on one surface (e.g. polished wood) will not necessarily be fair on another surface (e.g. baize).

Comment: @TonyK: is your statement true about six-sided dice?

Comment: @DavidQuinn, propbably not due to symmetry of the six-sided dice. A symmetric dice has the same physical interaction with the surface, no matter the part contacting the surface. A non-symmetric five sided dice will have different friction and torque applied to it if the first time it hits the surface it is on an edge between 2 rectangular faces or an edge between a rectangular face and a triangular face.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the same arguments as presented in [my solution to the physical biased coin problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1879731/357390) for determining the **exact** height of the triangular prism. As stated in the comments there, this is effective if the dice loses most of its energy in the first bounce.

Consider the pyramid in the prism with a base coinciding with one of the triangular sides and an apex at the geometric centre, which is obviously the centre of mass too. We know that the solid angle in a right pyramid with a regular *n*-gonal base of circumradius *r* and height *h* is
$$2\pi - 2n \tan^{-1}\left(\frac {\tan \left({\pi\over n}\right)}{\sqrt{1 + {r^2 \over h^2}}} \right)$$
Fix *r* = 1 and *n* = 3, then the fraction of the sphere subtended by the triangular base for our case is
$$\frac12 - \frac3{2\pi} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac {\sqrt3}{\sqrt{1 + {1\over h^2}}} \right)$$
and this must equal 1/5 for the dice to be fair. Solving, we get $h=\sqrt{\frac{3\sqrt5-5}8}$. The rectangular sides have height $2h$ and width $\sqrt3$, so they are shorter than they are wide with an aspect ratio of
$$\sqrt{\frac{3(5+3\sqrt5)}{10}}=1.874156\dots$$
The same technique can be used to construct fair d7's as pentagonal prisms, for which the rectangles are *taller* than they are wide with an aspect ratio of
$$2\tan\frac\pi7\sqrt{\frac2{(5-\sqrt5) (5-2\sqrt5-\tan^2\frac\pi7))}}=1.506037\dots$$
And so on and so forth, with d11 as a nonagonal prism, d13 as a hendecagonal prism, etc. (See also [my problem of constructing a hendecagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876590/how-to-construct-the-11-gon-and-polynomial-transformations-to-chebyshev-form).) However, these are not really practical.

Comment: We have been printing dice with a 3D printer and then carrying out rolls on a hard surface. At this point, this answer with solid central angles explains much of the situation, but it is significantly different from reality. The center of gravity also plays a part because it take less energy for a die to roll from a face with higher center of gravity to a face with a lower center of gravity than vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative idea:  use multiple rolls of an ordinary cubic die to approximate the fair five-sided one.  You add up $n$ rolls and divide by $5$, then the remainder is $0,1,2,3$, or $4$ with probabilities as nearly equal as possible given $6^n$ roll permutations.  Thus with $n=3$ you have $44$ permutations with remainder $3$ and $43$ permutations with each of the other remainders.

Comment: A simpler way to get a fair 5 way result from a six sided die would be to re-roll any sixes. Of course the number of rolls needed would be indeterminate, but the probability that n rolls is insufficient is 1/6^n.